# How to make an array the label text?

Tags: swift, xcode

So currently, I have an array that looks like this: ["Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3"]

I want to put them into a label so that they look as follows"

|  Name 1  | 

|  Name 2  |

|  Name 3  |

How would I go about doing this?

Also, as a bonus question, I have a lot of data in some arrays and so how can I create a scroll view in the middle of my screen that is big, but doesn't take up the entire screen, so that I can display all my data without having to compromise text size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, and easiest, idea that comes to mind, is just make 3 labels and constrain them as you wish.  Secondly, you could create a UITextView, instead.

```
let tView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthOfLongestWord, height: whatever height fits 3 lines))
tView.text = ""
for str in array {
    tView.text += str + "\n"
}
```

I assume this is being used in a view controller, in which case you should set the frame to zero and just constrain the textView with autoLayout.

Comment: So should I put this in the ViewController.swift file? Also, how would I do that second line if I have a random number of values in an array?

Comment: @kimsanity7 I edited it to handle different array sizes.  This should go somewhere in `viewDidLoad` (A View LifeCycle function in ViewController.swift)

Comment: thanks so much. I'm really new to swift so I appreciate all the help that everyone is giving me